# Как найти максимальное значение поляв БД?

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Итак, есть поле idpostmol в котором записаны данные вроде: postmol1 ... postmol11. ЕСли использовать простой запрос на поиск максимального значения, то postmol9 будет максимальным значением, хотя существуют postmol10 и postmol11. Каким образом можно сравнивать только цифры после postmol ? Т.е. запрос выводил максимальным 11, а не 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(TRIM(LEADING 'postmol' FROM `idpostmol`) AS UNSIGNED)) AS n FROM `table`;
```

Но лучше такими извращениями не заниматься, а придумать как ввести целочисленный ID.